# SQL Code to return only certain rows from a group

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would appreciate help with the following problem
I am trying to write a code to achive the fo;;woing.

I have a sample table below called details which has the follwoing columns:

| Ref | unique_f | splitlevel | cost_code | name | split |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 20221CBP AccoutCode 100 MR aaa bbb | AccountCode | 20221CBP | Mr aaa bbb | 100 |
| 1234 | 20221CBP SplitCode MR 28 aaa bbb | SplitCode | 20221CBP | Mr aaa bbb | 28 |
| 1234 | 20221CBP SplitCode 72 MR aaa bbb | SplitCode | 20221CBP | Mr aaa bbb | 72 |
| 4567 | 2022CBO AccountCode 100 Mr xxx yyy | AccountCode | 2022CBP | Mr xxx yyy | 100 |

what I need to achieve is if a person for example in above table Mr aaa bbb has rows which has split level = split code then only returns the slit for those people and those who only have an splitlevel = account code and no Split code to return the account Code. so in the example of the bove table I need my result to show:

| Ref | unique_f | splitlevel | cost_code | name | split |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 20221CBP SplitCode MR 28 aaa bbb | SplitCode | 20221CBP | Mr aaa bbb | 28 |
| 1234 | 20221CBP SplitCode 72 MR aaa bbb | SplitCode | 20221CBP | Mr aaa bbb | 72 |
| 4567 | 2022CBO AccountCode 100 Mr xxx yyy | AccountCode | 2022CBP | Mr xxx yyy | 100 |

the result above only has three rows because Mr aaa bbb has splitlevel= SplitCode and also Splitlevel-AccountCode but I need to ognore the row wth AccountCode for that person and only return the rows with splitCode in Split level however as Mr xxx yyy only has one row with split=level= Account Code then just briong that row for Mr xxx yyy.

I hope Ibhave clear in what I want to acieve by do not know how to achieve the above result,. I used row_nukber partion by date which I have in my actual table but can not seem ti achie =ve the ideal result.
Anyhlp is apprecaited

Comment: The tags here don't make any sense. How are both MySQLi (a PHP library for MySQL) and MSSQL-JDBC (a driver to connect to SQL Server from Java) both related to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
left join (
  select ref from t where splitlevel = 'SplitCode' group by ref
) x on x.ref = t.ref
where x.ref is null and t.splitlevel = 'AccountCode'
   or x.ref is not null and t.splitlevel = 'SplitCode'
```

Result:

```
Ref  unique_f                           splitlevel  cost_code name       split 
---- ---------------------------------- ----------- --------- ---------- -----
1234 20221CBP SplitCode MR 28 aaa bbb   SplitCode   20221CBP  Mr aaa bbb    28    
1234 20221CBP SplitCode 72 MR aaa bbb   SplitCode   20221CBP  Mr aaa bbb    72    
4567 2022CBO AccountCode 100 Mr xxx yyy AccountCode 2022CBP   100         null
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2EzlXpt-).

Comment: sorry tis comment was for yu. Hi, I am so sorry but I had something wrong with my table (in my question). I have tried your code and is very close but I get only AccountCodes back and not the SplitCode. Not sure because my table was misleading, hence I have corrected it now – 
any further advise will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use max() window function to get each person's max splitlevel value. Return the rows where the splitlevel value is the same as the max splitlevel. I.e. for users having only AccountCode or SplitCode, return those rows. For users having both AccountCode and SplitCode, return the SplitCode rows.

```
select Ref, unique_f, splitlevel, cost_code, name, split
from
(
  select t.*, max(splitlevel) over (partition by Ref) maxsplit
  from t
) dt
where splitlevel = maxsplit
```

@The Impaler's demo extended: https://dbfiddle.uk/yzcRD5ZE

Comment: tis worked great, thank  you so much